# how to decrypt SAMLResponse received from Shibboleth IdP

Tags: java, encryption, shibboleth, opensaml, service-provider

I am a college student trying to implement a service provider plugin for WebSSO in java. I am using Shibboleth IdP as identity provider. I have been able to send the authentication request to IdP and is successfully receiving the response from IdP through a servlet. I tried decoding the response and was able to get the XMLObject. Now the issue is that the response is encrypted. So when I am using

```
Assertion assertion = response.getAssertions().get(0);
```

It basically returns null. But when I am using

```
Assertion assertion = response.getEncryptedAssertions().get(0);
```

It is not null. So it basically means that the response is encrypted. Now I don't know the flow of how to decrypt the SAMLReponse. Any pointer, code or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this(replace `yourCredential` with your `Credential` object):

```
StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver keyresolver =
  new StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver(yourCredential);

Decrypter samlDecrypter = new Decrypter(null, keyresolver, new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());

Assertion assertion = samlDecrypter.decrypt(response.getEncryptedAssertions().get(0));
```

If your scenario is more complicated, a more detailed example can be found here on shibboleth's wiki: [Link](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManJavaXMLEncryption#OSTwoUserManJavaXMLEncryption-DecryptionExamples)

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. But I have one more issue now. I tried looking for Credential info but I'm not getting what exactly to supply to it. .pem files info or what? This is the only thing I found out in the configuration files, which close to Credential kind of information. Thank you so much. :) :)

Comment: You can read up on how to create credentials here: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPCredentials